# Objects losing rotation when rendering

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a problem with objects being reset when rendering a scene.

I have created a shape which I hope to 3d print by mirroring an object on the x and y axis. I have created a duplicate and rotated them to display over a plane for a render as can be seen in the first screenshot.

[image: objects rotated]

However, the moment I render the scene, the render shows both objects without any rotation, and when I go back to the 3d view, both objects have been reset to their initial rotational axis of 0,0,0.

[image: render no rotation]

[image: 3d View no rotation]

Can anyone help explain what's happening please! Thanks.

Comment: have you created some keyframes? Open your Dopesheet window to see it more easily

Comment: Do I need to use key frames if I'm not animating? I'm just trying to change their position for the render.

Comment: No you don't need, but your problem may come from the fact that you've created a keyframe with a certain position and when you render it comes back to this position, it will be easier to see if you open the Dopesheet and check, then delete the keyframe

Comment: Looks like a possibility then. I will update when I get home tonight and have a look.  Its true that I'm just starting with blender and may have mashed the keyboard once or twice to find a command and may have done somethibg unintended such as create a key frame.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. I had a keyframe on frame one.  Once I deleted that, the render works perfectly. THANK YOU!